# if subring of Ring R has no zero divisors, the can we say same about Ring R

Tags: ring-theory

can you give me Any example? - subring has zero divisors, while ring has no zero divisors.
But the statement holds true if subring is prime ideal.

Comment: The statement of the title is wrong. But clearly, subring cannot have zero divisors, while ring has none.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking different questions in the title and in the body of your post.

In the body you ask: is there a ring $R$ having no zero-divisors but for which some subring $S\subseteq R$ has zero-divisors. This is not possible, because if $x$ is a zero-divisor in $S$, then by definition $x\neq 0$ and there exists $y\in S$, $y\neq 0$, such that $xy=0$. But then $x$ and $y$ are zero-divisors in $R$ as well.

In the title, you ask, using the notation above, if there exists an $S\subseteq R$ having no zero-divisors, then is it true that $R$ has no zero-divisors. This is definitely false. Lots of rings having zero-divisors have subrings with none, such as subrings which are fields. Namely, for any field $k$, any finite-dimensional (commutative) $k$-algebra $R$ contains (a canonical copy of) $k$, but $R$ has no zero-divisors if and only if it too is a field. For example, $R=k[X]/(X^2)$ is such a ring, with $X+(X^2)$ a nonzero nilpotent element (hence a zero-divisor).

Answer (score 0):

Consider direct products like $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$.